# How do you abbreviate the word "estatísticas"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

I'm trying to find a shorter version of the word "estatísticas" to use on an interface where I am restricted on space.

In English, you can abbreviate "Statistics" as "Stats". Is there an abbreviation that is commonly used in Portuguese? If not, what would be a shortened version that would be understandable and not look strange if absolutely needed?

Comment: According to the [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes): `estat.` or `estatíst.`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Esse comentário é uma resposta.

Comment: we used to abbreviate a lot of classes in my college, but whenever we had statistics classes, we would always refer to it as "Aula de estatistica" as opposed to our programming classes "Aula de prog".

Answer (score 2):

### Estat.

For journals title abbreviations, **Estat.** or **estat.** is used, for instance, by the [*Revista Brasileira de Estatística*](http://www.rbes.ibge.gov.br/), which is [abbreviated](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/hlas/portugues/journaltotal.html) to *R. Bras. Estat.* This is also the rule for  abbreviation  of  titles  to  periodicals  and other  serials set by the Brazilian Association of Technical Standards (ABNT), [NBR 6032](http://www.gepem.org/site/images/abnt6032comofazerabrevia%C3%A7%C3%A3o.pdf).

As [Valdeir Psr](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/2759/) points out in his comment, the *Academia Brasileira de Letras* provides a list of common abbreviations, which [includes](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes):

> estat. estatística
>
> estatíst. estatística

Of these, the first indeed seems more common (and useful) to me.

In physics, *Mecânica Estatística* is sometimes colloquially referred to as "mecstat", especially by students. Though I haven't seen any other context where "stat" is an accepted abbreviation of "estatística", using the English "**Stats**" in an interface might be an acceptable, if inelegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

As the friend has already commented we can use these two forms in a formal way:
estat. — estatística
estatíst. — estatística

But we can shorten in a more informal way in which everyone will understand what we are talking about, and the use of the English abbreviation in this case is also welcome, since they are related words, so using "stats" in this case would be no problem .